# pipe() and fork() to transer data from parent to child

Tags: c, linux, pipe, fork, child-process

I have to create a pipe and then a fork and allow parent and child process (1 child) communication.

In particular Parent reads from a file and writes on pipe the content of file (which is supposed to be huge) then child has to read from pipe and display on stdout the content of file.

gcc compiler is ok but nothing happen when I run the executable file.

Can someone help me with my code? Where did I go wrong and why?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define size 80

int main(int argc,char*argv[]){

    if(argc!=2){
        write(2,"Missing parameters on the command line\n",38);
        return 1;
    }


    int fd[2];
    pid_t  pid;
    int fd_in;
    int i;
    char buf[size];
    //create pipe for communication between parent and child in this case parent read the file at size bytes at time write into pipe then child write data on stdout received from father  
    if(pipe(fd)!=0){
           printf("Pipe failure\n");
           return 1;
     }

     pid=fork();
     if(pid<0){
          printf("Fork() failure\n");
          return 1;
     }
    if(pid>0){ // parent process

        close(fd[0]);// parent write into pipe ,close reading

        if(access(argv[1],F_OK)!=0){
            write(2,"Input file does not exists\n",35);
            return 1;
        }


        if(fd_in=open(argv[1],O_RDONLY)<0){
            printf("Cannot open for reading file %s\n",argv[1]);    
            return 1;   
        }
        while(read(fd_in,buf,size)>0){
            write(fd[1],buf,size);
        }
        close(fd[1]); // close write into pipe
        wait(0);
     }

    if(pid==0){ //Child process
        close(fd[1]);// child read from pipe, close writing 
        while(read(fd[0],buf,size)>0){
            write(1,buf,size);      
        }
        close(fd[0]);// close reading
        return 0;   
     }

    close(fd_in);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "   if(fd_in=open(argv[1],O_RDONLY)<0){" needs more () to work

Comment: Thank you  now it works perfectly !!!! I am a loser!!!!

Comment: Remove the 'I am a loser' (part of your) comment — it isn't helpful (and probably isn't accurate).  You can edit your comments for 5 minutes, so please be quick about it.

Comment: When compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings.  (for `gcc` at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu99` )   On the posted code this will result in 3 warnings that need to be fixed.

Comment: when outputting error messages due to returned values from system functions, use `perror()` so the reason the system thinks it failed is also printed.

Comment: this line: `write(2,"Input file does not exists\n",35);` is saying to output 35 characters, but the text is not that long, so garbage will be output after the actual text.

Comment: this loop: `while(read(fd[0],buf,size)>0){
            write(1,buf,size);` will output `size` bytes even when less than `size` bytes read`.  Suggest using the returned value from `read()` as the number of bytes to write.